# gwt, async callbacks and DRY

Tags: gwt, asynchronous

According to [the official doc](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC#invoke), an async callback should have 2 interfaces, one of them could be generated from the other. Not mentioning, it is very hard to follow call hierarchy this way. Isn't there a DRY way to define such interfaces?

> To add an AsyncCallback parameter to all of our service methods, you
> must define a new interface as follows:
>
> - It must have the same name as the service interface, appended with Async (for example, StockPriceServiceAsync).
> - It must be located in the same package as the service interface.
> - Each method must have the same name and signature as in the service interface with an important difference: the method has no
>   return type and the last parameter is an AsyncCallback object.

Answer (score 4):

Well, after you have defined your sync interface (the one implemented by your `RemoteServiceServlet` extension) you can generate the async interface using:

- the GWT Plugin for Eclipse, if you use Eclipse (see [here](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/gwt_rpc));
- the Maven GWT Plugin, if you use maven (see [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/async.html));
- [some](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-asyncgen/) [other](http://code.google.com/p/acris/wiki/CodeGenerationPlatform_Async) libraries.